# Passing ViewModel (containing request parameters) across Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have few questions based on following scenario:

I have a LoginController with following methods:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserObject user)
{

    Calling Besiness Service to Validate User againts DB (Using Repository)...  

    if (success)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Search", "Search");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

After successful login, I have to present a Search screen. I have a SearchController with following methods:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    return View(); // This returns a EMPTY Search Form.

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchView search)
{
    // Validate Search parameters...
    // I have to perform a search by calling Business Service and present results. I would like to use a seperate controller (PricingController) for this task.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pricing"); // Not sure if this is the correct way?
}
```

Now I would like to have a PricingController which will take "SearchView" ViewModel containing my search parameters and call a Business Service to get the pricing results and present it to the user.

Is this a correct approach? How do I pass the "SearchView" ViewModel containing my search parameters to PricingController from SearchController? I need access (data) to "SearchView" ViewModel throughout the application because user can add optional items based on initial search criteria and can modify this search criteria if required. Should I store "SearchView" ViewModel in Cache? I will be deploying my application in Web Farm and don't want to use Http Session. I will be using Cookies for managing user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

to pass on the model to another action you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchView search)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pricing", new { exactNameOfSearchViewParameter = search });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim. I know I can do that but is that a correct approach? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: to my knowledge this is the way to go if you want to return a view based on another view, I however would use the service which contains the search method directly in the action Search and render the view from there.

Comment: Thanks again. Regarding your second approach, I can call the Pricing Service inside "Search(SearchView search)" method and populate a PricingView View model but then how do I render the View? If I call "return View(Model)" then it won't change my URL in browser and hitting reload/refresh on browser would be an issue... If I call "RedirectToAction()" method then I loose data in my View Model. I hope I am making sense???

Comment: there are ways, but after reading more I would've had the search function in the service layer and have it return a result based on the search (i usually use something like  public IEnumerable<theObject>(string search, string splitOperand)) and have the Index ActionResult in the PricingController to take a querystring to display the result. But this is just how i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a pricing repository which deals with calculations of prices. Now inject this repository into each controller which needs to calculate prices and use it in the actions. This way you don't need any redirects, in each action which needs to work with prices simply call the appropriate method on your repository.

Comment: Thanks Darin. Its actually the "SearchView" ViewModel containing my search parameters which I need in multiple (70%) controllers and my Pricing results for Core components, add-ons, midfications etc would be based on the initial search criteria. Would you suggest injecting this information into my controllers? If so, what is the best way to inject this info?

Comment: You could write a custom controller factory and [inject dependencies into your controllers](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2009/03/12/applying-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-com-application.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think I would move the `Search` action method to the `PricingController`. It seems like it really belongs there, as you are doing a price-related search.

Then you don't have to worry about how to transfer data between controllers.

You can modify your view to post directly there:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("search", "pricing"); %>
...
<% Html.EndForm() %>
```

If you really need to pass data between controllers or actions, you can use `TempData`. Just make sure your controller / action / view still works when `TempData` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

First of all I'd stop thinking about it as of ViewModel. ViewModel is all about the View and closely relates to the View itself. What you're talking about is Data (a set of criterias to use throughout the application). So the question is likely not about passing ViewModels but about passing Data and saving/sharing State (of selected criteria).

You can have some kind of SearchCriteriaData DTO-class and use it in different ViewModels in your app wherever its needed. SearchViewModel itself may have the only parameter of SearchCriteriaData. Controller should not ever bother about maintaining state consistency, its just not its responsibility. It can just refresh it (using some service calls, e.g. SearchService) and forget and never think about who is going to use it.

Then Controller that needs such a search-criteria to use, not just relies on given querystring parameters but also extracts those criteria from SearchService (which gives us actual SearchCriteriaData) and appends it to its own specific ViewModel. With that you can never worry about State at controller level and control it somewhere else (that SearchService can even save those criteria in database if necessary).

So, let your Controllers be stateless as it should be and control the state with either querystring parameters or SearchService (that would extract current-user-defined search criteria from wherever it wants).